# How can I put spin on the ball?

Tags: worms-crazy-golf

I'm at the third hole in Worms Crazy Golf where it "teaches" you how to put spin on the ball.  From the graphic, you left-click and drag left for counter-clockwise spin or drag right for clockwise spin.  I tried this and, while it unlocked the achievement for my first spin shot, it doesn't work.  Rotating arrows appear around the ball to indicate that the game understands what I'm trying to do, at least, but the ball doesn't roll any differently than normal when it lands.

What do I need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  While the ball is in the air, click and drag in the direction you want the ball to roll, **and** keep holding the mouse button down until the ball hits the ground.  If the ground is not more or less level the spin will have very little effect.  It's a bit finicky and you may need to drag a few times while holding the button, especially to get the spin up to full speed.  With enough momentum you can also sometimes do it after the ball has hit the ground, oddly enough, effectively giving you fine-grained control over the final position of the ball.

As an aside, the spin of the ball affects its trajectory in the air as well.  Useful for adding distance to drives, and so on.

**Edit:** Holding the mouse button and using the arrow keys works and is much easier than dragging the mouse.

Comment: If it's similar to other golf games (or to RL), then you should also see more spin on less-powerful shots and less spin on more powerful shots. (Where the ball lands would theoretically affect spin as well, but that depends a lot on the game.)

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis I haven't noticed a correlation with power but I'll keep experimenting.